# how do I destroy a kendo grid that's inside a kendo tab?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

tab:

```
<div id="parentTabStrip">
            <ul>
                <li class="k-state-active">Titles</li>
                <li>Commercials</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="titlesGrid"></div>
            <div id="commercialsGrid"></div>
        </div>
```

On page load, the grid gets created:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var year = $("#txtYear").val();
        createTitlesGrid(year);
        createCommercialsGrid();
    </script>
```

I'm trying to destroy the grid on an event but the jquery selector isn't finding my grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var year = $("#txtYear").val();
            createTitlesGrid(year);
            createCommercialsGrid();

            $('#txtYear').on('change', function ()
            {
                debugger;

                $('#titlesGrid').data("kendoGrid").destroy();

                $('#commercialsGrid').data("kendoGrid").destroy();

                //var year = this.value;
                //createTitlesGrid(year);
                //createCommercialsGrid();
            });
        </script>
```

It keeps saying:

TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var kendoGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
kendoGrid.destroy(); // Unhook from DOM
$("#grid").remove(); // Remove from DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you're creating the kendo grid the right way, this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            var year = $("#txtYear").val();
            createTitlesGrid(year);
            createCommercialsGrid();

            $('#txtYear').on('change', function ()
            {
                debugger;

                $('#titlesGrid').data("kendoGrid").destroy();

                $('#commercialsGrid').data("kendoGrid").destroy();

                //var year = this.value;
                //createTitlesGrid(year);
                //createCommercialsGrid();
            });
       });
</script>
```

Try:

```
var grid = $('#titlesGrid').data("kendoGrid");
grid.destroy();
```

Documentation of kendo ui:
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-destroy

Comment: unfortunately thats not working. grid is being NULL. and that's due to the fact that jquery cannot find #titlesGrid.

Comment: no luck. by the way, if i inspect the DOM, i do not see the grid's DIV though it is created under the tab.

Comment: try searching it with `"titlesGrid"` instead of `'titlesGrid`'

Comment: tried it. like I said before, if I physically look at the DOM, I do not see <div id="titlesGrid"></div>

Comment: that's very strange, can you create a fiddle? so it's easier to solve the problem

Comment: is there something wrong with their website? i tried: http://jsfiddle.net/ and this is what i get: [Fiddler] The socket connection to jsfiddle.net failed. 
ErrorCode: 10060. 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:80